# VBA properties type

Tags: vba, excel, properties

I know this is ultra basic in VBA but i have searched on 6 books (VBA for dummies 2010, Excel Bible, Proffesional Excel Development: The deffinitive guide, VBA and Macros Excel Microsoft 2010, Excel programming with VBA, Microsoft Excel VBA Proffesional Projects) and noone gives a deffinition about the 3 types of properties read-only, write-only and read/write.

---

They probably think is way to basic to even mention in their books but hey if you believed as i that computers were electricity purification filters 11 months ago and know you wanna code now someone has to tell ya a clean cut explanation

**thanks for watching my question**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the names suggest

---

**Read Only Property** is a property from which you can read but not write to it. For example, For a range `.Text` is a Read Only Property

```
Msgbox Range("A1").Text
```

If you try to write to it, for example

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text = "Blah Blah"
```

then you will get the message showing an error `Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to set  the Text property of the Range Class`

---

**Write-only Property**  are moderately rare. Write Properties are simply properties that have `Property Let or Set` method but no `Get Method`.

```
Private MyName As String

Property Let sName(Value As String)
    MyName = Value
End Property
```

---

**Read/Write Property** is pretty self explanatory. You can read and write to it. For example, for a Range `.Value` is a Read/Write Property

```
Range("A1").Value = "Blah Blah"
```

**Extra Note: Courtesy @Mehow**

When you press <kbd>F2</kbd> in the Visual Basic Editor, the Object Browser pops up. If you click on any of the classes and then members of that class you can see in the left bottom corner which properties are read/write.

Comment: Thank you friend your answer covers me 100%

Comment: Thanks to you both :)

Comment: +1 In addition to this great answer there is an Object Browser when you hit F2 in VBE. If you click on any of the classes and then members of that class you can see in the left bottom corner which properties are read/write.

Comment: yup good point @Mehow :) Wonder how I missed that :) Let me add it to the answer.